# How to configure postfix to bcc an email as an attachment?

Tags: linux, email, postfix, attachment

I can configure postfix with e.g. `recipient_bcc_maps` to copy sender or recipient emails to an address. However what I need is to not just forward a copy of the original mail, but rather to compose a new blank email from the original sender/recipient and attach the original email as a .eml attachment. The destination is a 'dropbox' for a webapp and requires the email be forwarded as an attachment. What's a simple way to achieve this on Linux ?

Comment: this is a legit and well-formed question for a production issue we're trying to solve. why the downvote and with no explanation?   if you're such a guru, please be helpful by answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can achieve this by using content filters. See http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html. But keep in mind that any mail Postfix receives will invoke that filter/script. From a performance or security point of view it might not be the best solution.